# Could you build a "space tunnel system"?

Tags: space, aircraft, propulsion

With the limitation of fuel that can be taken on a space craft, would it make sense to build a propulsion system in space instead?
For example via rings that are aligned very well and are positioned every x miles from each other, that each speed up the spacecraft.

Technically I believe it could work because of the Poynting vector created by EM fields. Eg. the ring could be a huge capacitor which is depleted when the vehicle is inside it so the energy is transfered to a momentum. To charge the capacitor solar panels can be used.

Additional you could build on these "stations" a temporary habitat.

Someone must have already considered something like this. And I'm wondering why it has not been commercialized yet. Is it because this idea is technically not feasible, or is the alignment to hard to achieve, or...?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your idea.

The main one is conservation of momentum: if one of these boosting rings imparts a momentum to your spacecraft, it attains a momentum in the opposite direction. So the rings would drift quite significantly over time. Likely all you've accomplished is offloading the fuel from the spacecraft itself onto your rings. If a sufficient number of spacecraft were going both ways (so that the overall momentum cancels out), you might be able to save this idea. But that would require much larger space traffic than we currently have.

It's of questionable use anyway, however. The vast majority of fuel usage during a mission is during takeoff and course changes. You don't really need "boosters" along the way because once you get up to speed in a spacecraft, you keep that speed until something stops you.